# Merge two transparent webm videos with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge two transparent webm videos together while keeping their transparency using ffmpeg.

Main video: 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/medlike/logo.webm

Overlay video:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/medlike/cortina.webm

Reading trough ffmpeg wiki and some stackexchange answers I made this:

```
ffmpeg -i logo.webm -i cortina.webm -filter_complex 'overlay=format=rgb' -vcodec libvpx output.webm
```

The result:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/medlike/output.webm

The desired output should look like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/medlike/vinheta-completa.webm

ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 15 2015 22:16:36 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.5.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libquvi --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'logo.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.101
  Duration: 00:00:09.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 712 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 960x540, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'cortina.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.101
  Duration: 00:00:09.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 436 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 960x540, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
[swscaler @ 0x7f9512006800] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[libvpx @ 0x7f9511827000] v1.3.0
Output #0, webm, to 'output.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libvpx
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (vp8) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (vp8) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libvpx)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  245 fps=6.3 q=0.0 Lsize=     114kB time=00:00:09.80 bitrate=  95.6kbits/s    
video:112kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.853043%
```

Thanks

Comment: *Stream #1:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p* *Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p* Looks like your video doesn't have an alpha channel, if it did it would be *yuva420p*. See this post for more: http://bit.ly/1Es6KLK

Comment: That's what I thought, too.  `metadata: alpha_mode: 1` is from `libavformat/matroskadec.c`.  It means the alpha flag was set in the input webm.  `ffmpeg -h decoder=vp8` shows the vp8 decoder doesn't take any options, though.  So if it's not decoding to `yuva420p`, IDK how to change that.

Comment: Also, why are you telling `overlay` to output RGB?  I don't see anything in the docs about alpha-blending problems when operating in YUV space.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the issue, instead, I rendered both videos using PNG codec and successfully merged them using the overlay ffmpeg filter, and than converted it to webm

Comment: Anyone make any progress? I have a non-transparent video and want to just force the video to not have transparency?

Answer (score 4):

Since 2016-07-20, it's possible to decode properly a webm with alpha channel (VP8a or VP9a) but you need the `-vcodec libvpx` option. You must download an **FFmpeg** compiled after that date (or compile yourself with up-to-date commits) and use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i logo.webm -vcodec libvpx -i cortina.webm -filter_complex overlay -vcodec libvpx output.webm
```

Note that `-vcodec libvpx` is **before** the input that needs to be read using the alpha planes (in this case, is `cortina.webm` the overlaid video, thus we put the option just before it).

(As Mulvya states, the format conversion should be avoided in this case.)

Comment: Why `format=rgb`? Unnecessary and lossy given that the inputs are YUV and vpx encodes to YUV.

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice it (just copied his command and added the option). I correct it.